# Yahoo OAuth not providing tokens to other users?

Tags: oauth-2.0, yahoo-api

I am having an issue with OTHER USERS using my app.

Right now my app has a login button that sends the user to the yahoo API Request_Token here's the code.

```
var main = angular.module("main", ["firebase", "ngRoute"]);

main.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider
.when('/', {
    templateUrl: 'partials/login.html',
    controller: 'loginController'
})
.when('/:token', {
    templateUrl: 'partials/callback.html',
    controller: 'welcomeController'
})
.otherwise(
    {redirectTo: '/'
});
}]);

main.controller("loginController", function ($routeParams, $scope) {
$scope.login = function () {
    var clientID = "[redacted]";
    window.location.href = "https://api.login.yahoo.com/oauth2/request_auth?client_id=" + clientID + "&redirect_uri=http://www.acleanpairofshorts.com/fantasy&response_type=token&language=en-us";
}
});
```

The user SHOULD BE redirected to the callback.html view.. AND THIS WORKS FOR ME... however, my friends are telling me that they are being redirected back to the login view and there is no /access_token appended to the URL.. so this leads me to believe that Yahoo is not providing access tokens to anyone but me... does anyone know if they can spot anything wrong with my code?

Comment: avoid putting your true `clientID` token in the code sample

Comment: It's being caused by browsers outside of chrome.. Not sure why the redirect doesn't work outside of that browser...